# difference between standard error and robust standard error

Tags: standard-error, generalized-estimating-equations, robust-standard-error

What is the difference between standard error vs robust standard error?

How is the robust standard error calculated in the Generalized Estimating Equation context?

Comment: There are various ways to compute a robust standard error. We can't tell you if you don't give us context. "Robust standard error" mentioned where, used for what?

Comment: In the Generelized Estimating Equation

Comment: Are you referring to a particular "robust standard error"? e.g. are you talking about some kind of "heteroskedasticity"-robust standard error?

Comment: "heteroskedasticity"-robust standard error

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly, since there are other things you could have meant by "robust"

Comment: Here is an example for a robust s.e. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353922/eicker-huber-white-robust-variance-estimator/354170#354170