# Estimation accuracy differences in ANOVA regression predicted means

Tags: regression, anova, estimation, standard-error

When we encode categorical variables in a (generalized) linear model, the standard approach is to have one category subsumed by the intercept. Call this the “baseline” category.

By doing this and then using the differences between this baseline category and the other categories, don’t we assume less error in the estimation of the mean of the baseline category than in the estimation of the means of the other categories?

We have the uncertainty in estimating $\beta_0$ (mean of the baseline group) and uncertainty in estimating $\beta_k$ (difference in means between the baseline group and group $k$), so the uncertainty compounds when we want to estimate $\beta_0+\beta_k$ (mean of group $k$).

Isn’t this a (huge) problem?

I get why it would not matter for an ANOVA F-test, but for estimating individual group means, designing the regression to have a tighter estimation of the control group mean than the treatment group mean seems like a mistake, particularly since it is easy to avoid if we just encode every category with the usual 0/1 method and go without an intercept.

Comment: Hope this gets a good answer. You would expect that the mean of the treated group, β0+βk, could be more uncertain than the control group, β0, given the two sources of uncertainty. But testing it, it isn't the case. I guess because the compounding of the two variances is offset by their (negative) covariance? I.e., 
var(β0+βk) = Var(β0) + Var(βk) + 2Cov(β0,βk)

Comment: The comment by @Lachlan and the related thread [Co-variance of beta coefficients for Dummy Variable regression with intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/234958/237901) seem to answer this question. Also, consider what happens with the sum encoding `contr.sum` (and we know that the encoding changes the parametrization but not the model, so we can't get more accurate estimates of group means by choosing one encoding over the other).